# r: set ylim in a summary bar chart customized function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have my data:

```
test<-data.frame(matrix(data = runif(300,min = 1, max = 10000),ncol = 30,dimnames = list(1:10,c(paste0("A",1:10),paste0("B",1:10),paste0("C",1:10)))))
```

I would like to plot bar chart with stat = "summary" and customized function:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
test<-melt(test)
test$group<-gsub("[0-9]","",test$variable)
ggplot(test,aes(x=group,y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat = "summary",fun=function(x){log(mean(x))})
```

[image]

It works pretty good here, but when I set the `ylim`:

```
ggplot(test,aes(x=group,y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat = "summary",fun=function(x){log(mean(x))})+
  ylim(0,10)
```

It remove almost all my data:

```
Warning message:
Removed 298 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary).
```

I am aware that it is connected with my input data, but what if I want to set ylim based on the summarized data, which is shown in the graph? Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ylim, try scale_y_continuous()

```
    ggplot(test,aes(x=group,y=value))+
      geom_bar(stat = "summary",fun=function(x){log(mean(x))}) + 
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,10), oob = rescale_none)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience it is better to do all your transformations before *ggplot*

```
test %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(
    value = log(mean(value))
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(group,value))+
  geom_col()+
  ylim(0,10)
```